# EntityManager.setFlushMode() vs Query.setFlushMode()

Tags: java, jpa, orm, mariadb, eclipselink

**Some documentation references:**

Enum javax.persistence.FlushModeType

- AUTO:   (Default) Flushing to occur at query execution.
- COMMIT: Flushing to occur at transaction commit.

javax.persistence.EntityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType flushMode)

- Set the flush mode that applies to all objects contained in the persistence context.

javax.persistence.Query.setFlushMode(FlushModeType flushMode)

- Set the flush mode type to be used for the query execution. ***The flush mode type applies to the query regardless of the flush mode type in use for the entity manager.***

**Sample Code:**

```
PTEmp e = em.find(PTEmp.class, 7852L);
e.setName("AAA");

String updateSqlString = "UPDATE PTEmp SET name = :name WHERE id = :id";
TypedQuery<PTEmp> query = em.createQuery(updateSqlString, PTEmp.class);
query.setParameter("name", "BBB");
query.setParameter("id", 7852L);

query.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO); // <= in 2nd test-case 
                                        //    this line is commented
em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

System.out.println("query FMT: " + query.getFlushMode()); // Always print: AUTO
System.out.println("em    FMT: " + em.getFlushMode());    // Always print: COMMIT

em.getTransaction().begin();
query.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Test-cases: different combinations of FlushModeTypes for entityManager and query. Also shows the SQL logs:**

1. Test-case: explicitly query with AUTO FlushModeType (query.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO); uncommented):

   ```
   1594 Query     UPDATE PTEMP SET fullname = 'AAA' WHERE (ID = 7852)
   1594 Query     UPDATE PTEMP SET fullname = 'BBB' WHERE (ID = 7852)
   1594 Query     COMMIT
   ```
2. Test-case: implicit (Default value) query with AUTO FlushModeType (query.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO); commented):

   ```
   1616 Query     UPDATE PTEMP SET fullname = 'BBB' WHERE (ID = 7852)
   1616 Query     UPDATE PTEMP SET fullname = 'AAA' WHERE (ID = 7852)
   1616 Query     COMMIT
   ```

In both test cases the System.out.println() returns:

- query flushModeType: AUTO
- em    flushModeType: COMMIT

**My doubt:**

I don't understand why these two test cases execute the queries in different order; when the flushModeTypes in both cases are the same.
The consequence is that finally the 1st-test-case persists 'BBB' and the 2nd-test-case 'AAA'.

In my opinion both test cases ought to execute the sql query in the same order and the right order ought to be like in 1st-test-case (before: 'AAA', after: 'BBB'), because the query has flushModeType=AUTO the persistence context should be flushed to the db before execute the query.

My persistence provider: EclipseLink.

DB: mariadb.

Comment: getFlushMode is returning Auto on the query despite it not being set, which is why you see AUTO for both your cases - file a bug with EclipseLink to return null on the query.getFlushMode call. The spec (section 3.10.8 of the JPA 2.1) states that if it isn't set on the query, the behaviour looks to the EntityManager flush mode setting, so the behaviour you are seeing is correct.